# How to create array in JQuery using DOM extracted text values

Tags: jquery, text-extraction, dom-traversal

Using JQuery, I want to create an array such as [TextA, TextB, ... Text I]. These array elements are to be extracted from the html code similar to shown below. I'm beginner in this field and tried extrating single text value using:

```
$('a.curT',$( this )).text();
```

"But its not working" as I am no getting "Text E" as the desired output. Also I don't have idea how to create an array using the extracted values.

```
<li class="top1">
<a class="tc1" href="link" title="title">Some Text</a>
<div class="top2 current">
    <div class="column" style="width:25%">
        <ul>    
            <li class="class1"><a href="linkA" title="A"><strong>Text A</strong></a></li>
            <li class="class1"><a href="linkB" title="B"><strong>Text B</strong></a></li>
            <li class="class1"><a href="linkC" title="C"><strong>Text C</strong></a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>                    
    <div class="column" style="width:25%">
        <ul>    
            <li class="class1"><a href="linkD" title="D"><strong>Text D</strong></a></li>
            <li class="class2"><a href="linkE" title="E" class="curT"><strong>Text E</strong></a></li>
            <li class="class1"><a href="linkF" title="F"><strong>Text F</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="column" style="width:25%">
        <ul>    
            <li class="class1"><a href="linkG" title="G"><strong>Text G</strong></a></li>
            <li class="class1"><a href="linkH" title="H"><strong>Text H</strong></a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>    
    <div class="column" style="width:25%">
        <ul>    
            <li class="class1"><a href="linkI" title="I"><strong>Text I</strong></a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggstion in this direction will be very helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Any time you find yourself writing *"But its not working."* in a technical question, backspace over it and say what you expect it to do, what it's doing instead, and why you think that's not correct.

Comment: Do you want **all** of the `Text X` values? Just some of them? Just the one with the class `cur_T`? If just one, why an array?

Comment: I want All Text X values, I started with the one having specific class curT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to project an array from matched elements:

```
var textArray = $("li a strong").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
var a = new Array();
$("strong").each(function(index) {
    a[index] = $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the useful .each() function:

```
var texts = [];

$('a.curT').each(function() {
   texts.push($(this).text());
});
```